# Changing color of labels in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Anybody that has experience using JFreeChart, is there a way to change the color of my labels for my XY axes. Right now I'm using a `XYPlot` and I want to change the color of the labels on my axes. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use [`setTickLabelPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setTickLabelPaint%28java.awt.Paint%29) on the desired `Axis`.

Comment: Thank you that answered my question. For anybody else with this problem I got a little stuck with the fact that XYPlot's getDomainAxis() returns a ValueAxis. But I looked at the documentation and realized that Valueaxis is a child class of Axis.

Comment: Excellent. One nice feature of `JFreeChart` is that the API documents are built with the `linksource` option, so you can navigate by clicking on names.

Comment: Is it possible to change the paint color within one label? E.g. first word of the label in black and the second word in gray?

Comment: I seem to recall support for `AttributedString`, but I've not tried it.

Answer (score 3):

I used this code to change the color of all my labels:

```
private void setFontColor(Color fontColor) {
    JFreeChart chart = getChart();
    chart.getTitle().setPaint(fontColor);
    Plot plot = chart.getPlot();
    if (plot instanceof CategoryPlot) {
        setAxisFontColor(((CategoryPlot) plot).getDomainAxis(), fontColor);
        setAxisFontColor(((CategoryPlot) plot).getRangeAxis(), fontColor);
    } else if (plot instanceof XYPlot) {
        setAxisFontColor(((XYPlot) plot).getDomainAxis(), fontColor);
        setAxisFontColor(((XYPlot) plot).getRangeAxis(), fontColor);
    }
}

private void setAxisFontColor(Axis axis, Color fontColor) {
    if (!fontColor.equals(axis.getLabelPaint()))
        axis.setLabelPaint(fontColor);
    if (!fontColor.equals(axis.getTickLabelPaint()))
        axis.setTickLabelPaint(fontColor);
}
```

If you use subtitles, you need to add them too.